# mod_rewrite not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using Laravel 5.5, when trying to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/search/357 I am getting a page cannot be found error. Non of the other solutions have worked for me. My .htaccess file resides in the root directory and looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase "/test/"

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/ # <=== NEW LINE!!!!
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


RewriteRule ^/test/search/(.*)$ /test/search?m_id=$1&a=1 [QSA, L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have syntax error. You open IfModule twice but close just once. Apart from that I don't think it's a good idea to use htaccess redirect instead of routing in laravel and properly set up virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^test/search/(.*)$ /test/search?m_id=$1&a=1 [QSA, L]
```

Without left / in htaccess RewriteRule
And place the rule before # Handle Front Controller